# Paypal IPN call - fsockopen timeout

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, fsockopen

> Warning: fsockopen()
>   [function.fsockopen]: unable to
>   connect to www.paypal.com:443
>   (Connection timed out)

This has worked previously? And suddenly has stopped working.
Any ideas?

This is the call:

```
$fp = fsockopen ('www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Wait, are you trying to do SSL over plain sockets...?

Comment: have tried sll://www.paypal.com on port 80 also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error your system is providing, it's timing out on the outbound connection, are you currently able to connect to www.paypal.com on port 443 though something like telnet?

Running something like: telnet www.paypal.com 443 from the local box should show if it's connecting.  I strongly suspect that something is blocking port 443 outbound, which is causing your issue, as it's unlikely that PayPal would block you for use of their IPN services.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Just tried connecting via telnet successfuly :   telnet www.paypal.com 443
Trying 66.211.169.65...
Connected to www.paypal.com.

Comment: heres the traceroute response from the server if this helps anybody help me!